# Simple Javascript onclick image gallary is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I've tried to apply similar code to an existing Stackoverflow topic which applies the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/zsNF5/4/

The problem is: I get the message `Uncaught ReferenceError: ic1 is not defined` when I click my button.

```
function ImageCollection(images) {
    this.images = images;
    this.i = 0;

    this.no = function(imgId) {
        var img = document.getElementById(imgId);
        this.i++;
        if (this.i == images.length)
            this.i = 0;
        img.src = images[this.i];
    }

    this.yes = function(imgId) {
        var img = document.getElementById(imgId);
        this.i++;
        if (this.i == images.length)
            this.i = 0;
        img.src = images[this.i];
    }
}

var ic1 = new ImageCollection(
    ['images/test.jpg', 'images/no1.jpg', 'images/no2.jpg']
);
```

The variable `ic1` is defined in the code, that's why I'm confused.

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Face or no face</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <script type="javascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="title">
    <h1 >IS THIS A FACE?</h1>
</div>
<img class="photo" src="images/test.jpg">
<div class="container">
    <form method="post" action="store.php">
        <input type='button' class="button1" value='NO' onclick='ic1.no("container")' />
        <input type='button' class="button2" value='YES' onclick='ic1.yes("container")' />
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope I'm clear as my JS skills are obviously very limited. Thanks!

Comment: Where's the script getting included into the HTML? Is it in the javascript.js file?

Answer (score 2):

You're using `var` keyword to define `ic1`. This limits it to the closest scope which might not be window. To define it as a global do

```
window.ic1 = new ImageCollection(
    ['images/test.jpg', 'images/no1.jpg', 'images/no2.jpg']
);
```

Comment: I changed it but sadly I still get the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your `<img id='container'` like in your example in the link?

This is the html code from the working example-

```
<img id='container' src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/bla bla bla base 64" >
<input type='button' value='next' onclick='ic1.next("container")' />
<input type='button' value='prev' onclick='ic1.prev("container")' />
```

And this is your code with class and not id

```
 <div class="container">
```

And in your function you are looking for var `img = document.getElementById(imgId);`

So try to replace class with id like `<div id="container">`